# how to update an array using rapidjson?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

i doing some stuff with rapidjson and i want to add values to an array i just created like that

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"
using namespace std ;

int main() {


    char json[1024];
    rapidjson::Document document ;
    document.Parse<0>(json);
    if (!document.IsObject()) {
            document.SetObject();
    }
    assert(document.IsObject());
    rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();
    // adding member (int)
    document.AddMember("mohammed",25,allocator);
    assert(document.HasMember("mohammed"));
    cout << document["mohammed"].GetInt() << endl ;

    // adding member (array)
    rapidjson::Value array(rapidjson::kArrayType);
    array.PushBack(5,allocator);
    array.PushBack(6,allocator);
    cout << array[0u].GetInt() << endl ;
    cout << array[1].GetInt() << endl ;
    document.AddMember("array",array,allocator);
    assert(document.HasMember("array"));
    assert(document["array"].IsArray());
    // here the following line give me an error 
    array.PushBack(7,allocator);




}
```

the error is

```
json: rapidjson/document.h:397: rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>& rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::PushBack(rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>&, Allocator&) [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<>]: Assertion `IsArray()' failed.
```

Aborted (core dumped)

what is the problem can someone explain? what is happening i am kinda new to this,thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `array.PushBack(...)` is being executed, `array` has already been **moved** into `document`, and becomes a null value type (`array.IsNull() == true`). So you cannot `PushBack` to a null value.

`document["array"].PushBack(7,allocator)` will work.

Comment: good thing to have my question answered from the one who wrote the library, thank you, and BTW, this library is giving me hard time, i am required to use it in a project and i am kinda lost there.

Comment: That PushBack causing the rapidjson::Value to not be valid anymore is so easy to forget, that and to remember to use an allocator when you create a rapidjson::Value outside of the current document!